# Enable iOS On-Disk Encryption

Tags: iphone, cocoa, encryption, ios6, data-protection

For my iOS 6+-only app, I would like to enable the On-Disk Encryption offered from iOS.

I read [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html) and I saw the "Protecting the User's Data" video of the WWDC 2012 (Session 714). However, I could not make it work.

Here are the steps I followed:

**1-** In the [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), I created  a new App ID with:

[image: Enable for Data Protection]

**2-** In Xcode, I added an Entitlements file with the key:

[image: Xcode Entitlements]

**3-** On the device, I activated a passcode lock.

If I'm not wrong, this should be all. I now expect that while the device (in my case: an iPhone 5) is locked, protected files are inaccessible. But... if I use [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), I can easily access the files created by my app, even when the device is locked. But this is **exactly** what I want to avoid. Did I forgot something?

Comment: The newer guide for it may be at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can access files without unlocking your device is that an escrow keybag has been created. This is explained in Apple's [iOS Security Guide (pdf)](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf):

> Escrow keybag is used for iTunes syncing and Mobile Device Management (MDM). This keybag allows iTunes to back up and sync without requiring the user to enter a passcode, and it allows an MDM server to remotely clear a user’s passcode. It is stored on the computer that’s used to sync with iTunes, or on the MDM server that manages the device.
>
> The Escrow keybag improves the user experience during device synchronization, which potentially requires access to all classes of data. When a passcode-locked device is first connected to iTunes, the user is prompted to enter a passcode. The device
> then creates an Escrow keybag and passes it to the host. The Escrow keybag contains exactly the same class keys used on the device, protected by a newly generated key. This key is needed to unlock the Escrow keybag, and is stored on the device in the Protected Until First User Authentication class. This is why the device passcode must be entered before backing up with iTunes for the first time after a reboot.

If you reboot your phone, you will not be able to access files without unlocking it once.

Comment: Seems like the link provided above is broken. Updated link is https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want that files to be available **only** when device is unlocked(+about 10 seconds of grace period), set file protection to NSFileProtectionComplete. Be sure to implement delegate methods to know when data will become [un]available.